# React - Changing state property value (a boolean) with a function taking a string parameter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to write a function to expand/collapse the length of list of filter options. It's the first time I've used redux for props, but I think that part of the code is working fine.

I'm pretty sure the problem is the function to toggle the property value that determines whether to display the expanded or collapsed list.

Here's the button that calls the toggle function from the component and the toggle function:

```
<a className={s.filter_expand} onClick={this.switchTokensToShow.bind(this)}>
  {this.props.allFilters.tokens.length >= 6 ? (this.shouldDisplayAllTokenFilters() ? (
     <span>Show less</span>
  ) : (
     <span>Show more</span>
  )) : null



switchTokensToShow() {
  this.props.filter_list_number('tokens');
}
```

Some redux code connecting the function to the state...

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    filter_list_number: (filterType) => dispatch(filter_list_number(filterType)),
  };
 }

export function filter_list_number(filterType) {
  return{
    type: FILTER_LIST_NUMBER,
    filterType: filterType,
  }
 }

export const FILTER_LIST_NUMBER = 'FILTER_LIST_NUMBER';
```

And the function blocks that return the props...

```
  expandedFilters: {
    categories: false,
    tokens: false,


 case FILTER_LIST_NUMBER:
  const newFilterSettings = toggleExpandedFilter(
    {expandedFilters},
    action.filterType,
  );
  return {
    expandedFilters: {
      newFilterSettings,
    },
  };


  function toggleExpandedFilter(filterSettings, filterType) {
    return !filterSettings.filterType;
  }
```

It's the function at the end that's giving me the problems. The filterType value is always one of two strings ("tokens" or "categories" and I'm trying to figure out how to target/change the boolean value of the corresponding filterSettings property.

As of right now, the block flips the value of BOTH the expandedFilters properties, and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems.

I'm not exactly sure why the ! operator construction wasn't targeting the specified key, but it was just returning a single boolean value in place of an object. This code ended up working though:

```
function toggleExpandedFilter(filterSettings, filterType) {
  if (filterSettings[filterType] === false) {
    filterSettings[filterType] = true;
  } else {
    filterSettings[filterType] = false;
  }
  return filterSettings; 
}
```

Second, in the CASE return, my original argument was returning the variable newSettings as a value of expandedFilters INSIDE curly brackets:

```
const newFilterSettings = toggleExpandedFilter(
   {expandedFilters},
   action.filterType,
  );
 return {
  expandedFilters: {
  newFilterSettings,
 },
};
```

So it was nesting the key values of categories: and tokens: one level below what the component block was trying to access. That means this...

```
expandedFilters: {
  newSettings:  {
    categories: false,
    tokens: false,
  },
}
```

Was happening instead of..

```
  expandedFilters: {
    categories: false,
    tokens: false,
  }
```

The fix ended up being this:

```
   return {
    ...state,
    expandedFilters: newFilterSettings,
  };
```